# Is there a way to fetch data based on user assigned permissions on Cosmos DB?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb

- I have a container in **CosmosDB** that contains information about some
  countries.
- I have a **Storage** table that contains the user access    permissions
  on specific countries.

I.E the user **testmail@test.com** can access the **USA, UK** only countries.

1. In my azure function, after successfully authentication i got the
   user email.
2. I perform a search on the user permission storage table to
   fetch the specific user countries access.
3. Manipulate the query string with the fetched user countries string
   to make the final query.

**Is this a proper way to fetch resources from CosmosDB based on user assigned permissions?**

If it's not:

**How to assign custom permissions on azure active directory to fetch data based on that permissions?**

**The code below works.**

Here is the body of the function:

```
//**GET THE USER INFO**
var user = req.Authenticate();

//**GET THE USER PERMISSIONS**
var userPermissions = await new CalculateUserPermissions().GetPermissions(user.UserId);

//**GET THE USER COUNTRIES ['USA', 'UK']**
List<string> countries = userPermissions.Countries;

StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder(@"
    SELECT 
     c.country,
     c.code,
     c.info,
    FROM c");

if (countries == null)
{
   query.Append($" GROUP BY c.country, c.code) as root");
}
else
{
   query.Append($" WHERE");

   foreach (string country in countries)
   {
      query.Append($" c.code = '{country}' OR");
   }

   string builtQuery = query.ToString();

   // TRIM THE LAST 'OR'
   builtQuery = builtQuery.Substring(0, builtQuery.Length - 3);

   query = new StringBuilder(builtQuery);
      query.Append($" GROUP BY c.country, c.code");
   }
}

...call the database with the query string...
```

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB does not currently support Azure AD authentication or authorization. It does have it's own user and [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#permissions) model that you can map between your AAD users and Cosmos but you can only assign permissions down to the partition key level. There is no support for row-level permissions in Cosmos DB.

If the number of countries is not too large, I think it would be easier to simply create a container of users and embed country codes as an array within each user.